# React way? EditBox toggles edit/readonly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a learning React, and want to know if I am making beginner mistakes. I created this EditBox. Its meant to serve as a wrapper for a panel with value and if you click the edit button it will switch to an editable form. Both panel and form are passed in. Also an initForm routine and a title. The box is used for some 20 different forms.

- setEditing will call the initForm method passed in to set the initial values of the form when editing starts. Is there a better way to connect this setEditing to trigger an event in de form passed?
- The form needs to be passed in as a function that accepts the save/cancel buttons as a function that accepts isSubmitting (this way also the buttons are DRY).isSubmitting is a state variable of the use form that can make the submit button disabled. This seems a little complicated but got the thing I wanted done. Is there a less complicated, more readable solution for this?
- the panel also needs to be passed in as a function that accepts the setEditing method. Since sometimes the readonly panel contains an alternate button to also set the EditBox in edit mode.

```
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
    import { faPen, faSave } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
    import styles from "./EditBox.module.scss";
    import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

    let cx = classNames.bind(styles);

    class EditBox extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
              isEditForm: false
            };
        }

        setEditing = (value) => {
            if (value && this.props.initForm) {
                this.props.initForm();
            }
            this.setState({ isEditForm: value });
        }

        render() {
            return  <div className={cx('editbox', this.state.isEditForm && 'editing')}>
                        <h4>{this.props.title}</h4>
                        {!this.state.isEditForm && <button className={cx('edit-button')} onClick={() => this.setEditing(true)}><FontAwesomeIcon size='lg' icon={faPen} /></button>}
                        {this.state.isEditForm ? 
                            this.props.form((isSubmitting) =>   <div className={cx('buttons')}>
                                                                    <button className={cx('submit')} type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Bewaren <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave} style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}/></button>
                                                                    <button className={cx('cancel')} onClick={() => { this.setState({ isEditForm: false }) }}>Annuleren</button>
                                                                </div>, this.setEditing)
                        :
                            this.props.panel(this.setEditing)
                        }
                    </div>
        }
    }

    export default EditBox;
```

I understand its a little complicated code. But I would be very happy if someone could look in to it :-)

To illustrate the behaviour (as requested):

[image]
Above: Readonly mode pencil (part of EditBox) and yellow area of panel will switch component to edit mode

[image]
Above: Edit mode, buttons belong to EditBox and both will in the end switch back to readonly mode

Jacco

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the behavior that you want. You talk a bit about what props you want passed in and what kind of functions there are... but how should it *look* and how should it *behave*? Ignore the implementation for a moment and focus on describing *what* you want to have happen, **not** *how* you want it to happen.

Comment: from what i understand you want a `TextInput` with two buttons which control if the TextInput is editable or readonly. if yes then i would have the two buttons control the `disabled` property of TextInput.

Comment: Edited the question to explain better